# Querying both aggregate and analytical aggregate on the same Big Query query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using Big Query, I am trying to query
**count(distinct *col*), count (distinct *col*) over (partition by *col2*)**

But I receive an unexpected error.

Here is the template of the query i'm trying to execute:

```
SELECT
          country,
          partner,
          segment_id,
          COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id) pvs,
          COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id) over(PARTITION BY country) country_total_pvs
FROM (...)
GROUP BY
          country,
          partner,
          segment_id
```

And the error I keep getting:

> Error: Expression 'pv_id' is not present in the GROUP BY list

Without the 5th column (the analytical count), the query executes without any error.

Thoughts?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would explain what you want to do.  As written, the query is not valid, so it doesn't really convey your intent.

Comment: Here, you can take following code for example:<br/> `SELECT
  language,
  title,
  COUNT(DISTINCT contirbutor_username),
  COUNT(DISTINCT contirbutor_username) over(
  PARTITION BY
    language)
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia]
GROUP BY
  language,
  title`      what I really want to have is grouping result of different dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, but I'm guessing does not do what you want:

```
SELECT country, partner, segment_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id) pvs,
       SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY country) as country_total_pvs
FROM (...) q
GROUP BY country, partner, segment_id;
```

Instead:

```
SELECT country, partner, segment_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id) pvs,
       country_total_pvs
FROM (SELECT q.*,
             COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id) OVER (PARTITION BY country) as country_total_pvs
      FROM (...) q
     ) q
GROUP BY country, partner, segment_id, country_total_pvs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT
  a.country AS country,
  partner,
  segment_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id) pvs,
  country_total_pvs
FROM youTable AS a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT country, COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id) country_total_pvs
  FROM youTable GROUP BY country
) AS b
ON a.country = b.country
GROUP BY
  country,
  partner,
  segment_id,
  country_total_pvs
```

Have in mind  - above will provide "correct" distinct counts for BigQuery StandardSQL, but in BigQuery Legacy SQL [COUNT(DISTINCT)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#countdistinct) is a statistical approximation and is not guaranteed to be exact. You can use [EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#exact_count_distinct) instead

Below is slightly optimized version

```
SELECT
  a.country AS country,
  partner,
  segment_id,
  pvs,
  country_total_pvs
FROM (
  SELECT
    country,
    partner,
    segment_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id) pvs
  FROM youTable 
  GROUP BY country, partner, segment_id
) AS a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT country,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pv_id) country_total_pvs
  FROM youTable GROUP BY country
) AS b
ON a.country = b.country
```